# How to have a 3/4 full screen size ad in ios?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iad

I would like to be able to ad an advertisment that I can make popup whenever I desire but that does not take up the entire screen, A perfect example of what I desire visually is below:

I am not looking for any exact code, but more or less asking which framework to use. I know iAd will not support this type of advertisment, but which one will?

---

Before Ad:                                                                             After Ad:

[image: App Before Advertisment.]
[image]

Comment: Most interstitial advertisements take up the whole screen.

Comment: @akashg are you saying what I am asking is impossible? Because The only reason I am asking Is because I see it alot.

Comment: I see this alot as well.

Comment: How about creating your own "UIAlertView" and display the content you want? I think UIAlertView uses its own window, which mean you could add your custom window on top of the application window to make it modal and have a delegate callback (or even better... blocks!) to dismiss the custom window. I would definitely look into this approach.

Comment: @bensarz thanks, post it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting comment as answer:

How about creating your own **UIAlertView** and display the content you want? I think `UIAlertView` uses its own window, which mean you could add your custom window on top of the application window to make it modal and have a delegate callback (or even better... blocks!) to dismiss the custom window. I would definitely look into this approach

**Edit:**
I would take a look at how Sam Vermette did his `SVProgressHUD`. That should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

These type of advertisement is called interstitial advertisement. I personally use Flurry and Millennial. They are good rich of ads and with high quality ads. They also have video ads, small banner ads etc. they also provide the ability to control your ads from their site. Read their docs.

Admob (from google) doesn't have the interstitial advertisements. But i use it in my Ad mediation.

The coding for these SDKs will be like couple of lines, not more.

http://www.millennialmedia.com/

http://www.flurry.com/

http://www.google.com/ads/admob/